# How do I Continuous Redirect with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to continuous redirect with Apache .htaccess.

I try this.

```
  Redirect 301 / https://fuumin.net 
  Redirect 301 / http://yuis.xsrv.jp/info/
```

and this too.

```
  Redirect 301 / https://fuumin.net
  Redirect 301 https://fuumin.net http://yuis.xsrv.jp/info/
```

I have no idea how to redirect Continuously.

How do I solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by _continous_ redirect?

Comment: like https://yuis.xsrv.jp/images/ss/ShareX_ScreenShot_1b50b188-4f4d-4457-b799-d22e66842019.png.

Comment: Meaning of several redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only redirect once.

- If you redirect to a location that is on the same server, then you can configure that location to redirect to the next.
- If you redirect to some other server, that server needs to redirect to the next one.

And repeat!